# php chown() issue with apache user

Tags: php, chown

I'm running a cron which is run under another user (not **apache**) and when I try to access **apache**'s files it shows an error like:

```
fopen(): SAFE MODE Restriction in effect. 
The script whose uid is 10017 is not allowed to access ....
```

It's because safe_mode is turned on and it doesn't let me use **apache**'s files (in this case uploaded files through the site). How can I overcome this? In php.net it says I have to be superuser to be able to change ownership which doesn't seem very secure to me ...

Comment: it depends upon what 'apache files' do you try to access

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You run the PHP script through the 'php' interpreter (from a cron job) rather than through Apache's mod_php. This means you can enable and disable PHP's safe mode as you please.

You should probably do something like `php -d safe_mode=0 myscript.php`.

Comment: Hey Ilya that might actually be the solution I'm looking for, I'm going to try this. Btw are you Bulgarian? Ilya? ... or Russian maybe :)

Comment: Ukrainian, but I'm a Russian speaker, yes :)

Answer (score 1):

Or call your cron via an http request.

```
wget -O - -q -t 1 http://yourdomain/myscript.php
```

Because it's done via the interwebs, Apache will be the user.

Comment: This is not a good solution for me because I'm using the cron for internal business only and have limited it to the cli only using a check like `if (php_sapi_name() != 'cli') exit;`. It adds an extra layer of security.